# AddRef() in VB6

Tags: com, vb6, reference, reference-counting

is it possible to call method AddRef() from interface IUnknown in visual basic 6 or implement some hack to increment object reference counter?

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to artificially increment the refrence counter (outside of the automatic reference counting that is done by VB6) then you can do the following:

```
Public Sub AddOneToRefCount(target As Object)

    Dim tempObj As Object
    Set tempObj = target 'VB6 calls AddRef for you here

    Call CopyMemory(ByVal ObjPtr(tempObj), 0&, 4&) 'trick VB into not calling Release

End Sub
```

You'll probably need to implement the reverse of this as well to release or you will get a memory leak of sorts.

Comment: But VB will call Release() when the Sub exits. The net effect is to call AddRef() once and then Release() once

Comment: @MarkJ - No it won't because the CopyMemory zeroes out the reference under the covers.  After the CopyMemory that reference is Nothing (null).  I've used this technique for breaking circular refrences in complex parent-child object graphs.

Comment: You can also reverse the process to create a `SubtractOneFromRefCount` routine as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly sure that VB6 doesn't support directly accessing the IUnknown methods.  But the workaround is simple.  Add this declaration to a Module:

```
  Dim ReferenceHolder As Variant
```

And then get AddRef() to get called with a simple assignment

```
  Set ReferenceHolder = someObject
```

Reversely, get Release() to get called with

```
  Set ReferenceHolder = Nothing
```

This is normal VB6 memory management at work.